# Import cv2 error python

Tags: python, opencv, symlink, importerror

Whenever I attempt to import cv2, I always get this error

```
import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name
```

I've already created a symbolic link and I have also already installed the libgdal-dev module from the Ubuntu Software Center. Any ideas? Thanks!

**EDIT**: I did as pbu suggested, and the link was created without fail for the most part. But now, this error comes up:

```
import cv2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: /usr/local/lib/libgdal.so.1: cannot read file data: Is a directory
```

Thank you all for your suggestions!

Comment: looks like the file is missing, search for it and copy to lib folder: `$locate libgdal.so` then `ln -s /usr/local/lib/libgdal.so /usr/lib `

Comment: consider accepting the answer (although it came so late), since it really solves this problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

was happen same with me , resolved after :

> GDAL 2.1 is available for Ubuntu 16.04 from the UbuntuGIS-Unstable PPA

```
sudo apt install gdal-bin python-gdal python3-gdal
```