# Post-Caffe install, Ubuntu 16.04 - /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, caffe, pycaffe

I am brand new to Linux and have a new PC with Ubuntu 16.04.  I am trying to install Caffe using this guide (as well as many others for troubleshooting, but this one is focused on Python 3):

https://yangcha.github.io/Caffe-Conda3/

After days of troubleshooting various errors, and inadequacies on my part, I have finally been able to make and install Caffe, with the caveat that I get this one flag

---

```
- Could NOT find Boost

-- Boost version: 1.58.0

-- Found the following Boost libraries:

--   python-py35
```

---

I have Anaconda with Python 3.6.3 so I'm not sure why it grabbed 3.5, but the cmake output lists Python 3.5.2 as the interpreter.  It also detects Cuda and cudnn and passes the make runtest just fine.

However, when I try to test my pycaffe with

```
python -c "import caffe;print(caffe.__version__)"
```

I get the following error:

---

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/caffe-rc5/python/caffe/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .pycaffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, RMSPropSolver, AdaDeltaSolver, AdamSolver, NCCL, Timer
   File "/usr/local/caffe-rc5/python/caffe/pycaffe.py", line 13, in <module>
    from ._caffe import Net, SGDSolver, NesterovSolver, AdaGradSolver, \
ImportError: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.1: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name
```

---

I found these discussions:

[Import cv2 error python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31273224/import-cv2-error-python)

[Caffe installation in ubuntu 17.04: Import Error: /usr/lib/libgdal.so.20: undefined symbol: sqlite3_column_table_name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47032171/caffe-installation-in-ubuntu-17-04-import-error-usr-lib-libgdal-so-20-undefi)

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/caffe-users/6K6zxt0RaHg/0CegZ7TyCQAJ

But have been unable to reproduce the various suggested solutions.  Note that I strongly prefer to not uninstall Anaconda, and I absolutely, 100%, want nothing to do with python2.

Could somebody please help me find a workaround for this?  I'm hoping it's trivial for somebody less Linux-challenged.  I apologize in advance for the explicit instructions I might need, as I have only been learning Linux for about a week and am still in very unfamiliar territory.  But I'm unfortunately on a timeline for making progress on a CNN project, so I'd really like to get Caffe up and running (albeit per the above conditions; as a passing thought I'd also love to fix the Boost flag and hopefully use python 3.6, but whatever I can do to avoid python2 is fine).

Please let me know if any other information or files might help.  Here is a link to my Makefile.config (as far I can tell my Python paths are correct, but again this is all very strange and unfamiliar to me, so it wouldn't surprise me to find out I've gone horribly wrong somewhere).

[Makefile.config](http://txt.do/dqzpr)